# I'm trying to include a SwiftUI chart in a UIkit viewController but i'ml not sure exactly how to do this

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a viewController in a storyboard. In the storyboard I have a section where i'd like to include a SwiftUI chart. I've investigated this and took example code from various sources but it's not working out.
The code compiled but i'm not seeing anything in the UI.

Below is the user interface I refer to:

[I want to include the chart here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0MQc.png)

Here is the code I have thats included in  super.viewDidLoad:

`

```
  // Revenue Chart
        
        // Create CGSize for a UIKit View and its sub view
        let size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
        let sizeSubView = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        
        // Create UIKit View
        let uiView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        uiView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        // Create a subview to be placed at the centre of above view
        // this will be a container view for the Swift UI View
        let centerPointForSubView = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: sizeSubView)
        let uiViewSubView = UIView(frame: centerPointForSubView)
        uiViewSubView.backgroundColor = .white

        // Add placeholder subview to UIKit View
        uiView.addSubview(uiViewSubView)
        
        struct Item: Identifiable {
            var id = UUID()
            let type: String
            let value: Double
        }

        struct ContentViewChart: View {
            let items: [Item] = [
            Item(type: "1", value: 100 ),
            Item(type: "2", value: 80 ),
            Item(type: "3", value: 120 ),
            Item(type: "4", value: 20 ),
            Item(type: "5", value: 55 ),
            Item(type: "6", value: 170 ),
            Item(type: "7", value: 20 ),
            Item(type: "8", value: 10 ),
            Item(type: "9", value: 5 ),
            Item(type: "10", value: 1 ),
            Item(type: "11", value: 500 ),
            Item(type: "12", value: 700 )
        ]
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    
                    Chart(items) { item in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Month", item.type),
                            y: .value("Revenue", item.value)
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.purple.gradient)
                    }
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .padding()
                }
                    .navigationTitle("Charts")
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Create a SwiftUI View
        let swiftUIView = ContentView()
        
        // Define a hosting VC.
        // A UIKit view controller that manages a SwiftUI view hierarchy.
        let host = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
        let hostView = host.view!

        // Add the SwiftUI view to the UIKit view
        uiViewSubView.addSubview(hostView)
```

`

When I run the app with the code above I see nothing what so ever in my UI. But it does compile with no errors.

As can be seen the values for the chart are currently hardcoded. That will be replaced with real data once I get the UI to work.

I've been playing with the code, checking blogs etc.

On the other hand i'm on a tight schedule to get this exercise done so any expert advice is most welcome.

Comment: You need constraints, add them right after add subview

Comment: Thank you but I think I need more guidance.

Comment: I did that but I still do not see anything in the UI so I guess the issue is elsewhere.